# error in coping argv[] to int array in c

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, argv

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <stdlib.h>
# include <stddef.h>
# include <sys/types.h>
# include <sys/ipc.h>
# include <sys/shm.h>
# include <sys/sem.h>
# include <unistd.h>
# include <time.h>
# include <math.h>

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
  int i,j,x,shM, *shmPtr;
 int *array_pid, *apotelesma, loops,y,N;
int *array1; 
double  a,b,temp;





shM=shmget(3002,sizeof(int),IPC_CREAT|0600);
shmPtr=(shM,0,0);


 array1=(int*)malloc((argc-2)*sizeof(int));

 if(array1==NULL)
 printf("error in array1");

for (i=0;i<=(argc-2);i++)
{
 array1[i]=atoi(argv[i]);

}

N=argc;
loops=atoi(argv[argc-1]);
array_pid=(int*)malloc(N*sizeof(int));

if (array_pid==NULL)
printf("error in array_pid");

apotelesma=(int*)malloc(N*sizeof(int));

if (apotelesma==NULL)
printf("error in apotelesma");

j=fork();

if (j>0)
{
 array_pid[i]=j;


for (i=0;i<loops;i++)
{

srand(time(NULL));

if (i>0)
apotelesma[i]=*shmPtr;

y=(rand()%(argc-2));

array1[y]=*shmPtr;
printf("y=%d apotelesma=%d",y,apotelesma[i]);



}




*shmPtr=-1;





for (i=0;i<N;i++)
wait();


shmdt(shmPtr);
shmctl(shM,0,IPC_RMID);

exit(0);
}

else  //child
{
while(1)
{

  x=*shmPtr;
  if(x<0)
{

 exit(0);
}
 a=rand();
 b=rand();
 temp=(pow((a-x/2),2)+pow((b-x/2),2));
 temp=sqrt(temp);
 if (temp<=x/2)
      *shmPtr=1;
     else
         *shmPtr=0;


    }


}

}
```

i'm posting again the whole code cause i am not really sure where the segmentation fault is. i think now that it might be shared memory that causes the problem. thanks for the information about counting argv.

Comment: your code is assuming there will be (at least) 2 parameters on the command line, after the program name.  Your code needs to verify that by comparing the value of argc

Answer (score 2):

For an array of length `argc-2`, only indexing of `0` to `argc - 3` are valid. So this

```
for (i=1;i<=(argc-2);i++)
```

is wrong because you are accessing `array[argc - 2]`. It should be:

```
for (i = 0; i < argc - 2; i++)
```

Note that there might be other errors causing the segmentation fault because you didn't provide how you call the program.

It's better to be defensive to process command line arguments. (i.e, check the validity of `argc`, etc).

Answer (score 0):

It is always better to check the `argc` value before going ahead when you pass command line arguments.

```
if(argc != /* num of arguments */)
return;

for (i=1;i<=(argc-2);i++)
```

This is wrong.

It has to be

```
for (i=0;i<argc-2;i++)
```